# How to encapsulate tapped traffic to forward over L2/L3 network?

Tags: ethernet, layer2

I am tapping some 10Gb ethernet links at some remote sites (normal passive fibre taps) for some QoS/QoE monitoring.  I don't have any dark fibre options at these sites to send the traffic back to a central monitoring site and I don't want to deploy the monitoring tools remotely.  The amount of actual traffic to send back for analysis is not huge, perhaps 2 or 3 Gb peak.  I can provide a simple Ethernet service to the site but this service does not have the option to disable MAC learning (so that all traffic on ingress would be broadcast).

Is there any solution that doesn't cost a fortune?  (GRE tunnels could work for example but require relatively expensive routers at each end).

If there was something that modified the Ethernet frame (replaced with another destination MAC address for example) that would be fine.

Any ideas welcome!

Comment: Does something like Cisco RSPAN not do the trick ? Or is the Ethernet service you are looking to use likely to have some feature which doesn't play nice with RSPAN's dedicated VLAN ?

Comment: I will need to check how RSPAN works - I don't have the option to transport VLAN tags on this service unfortunately so if it needs that it's not going to be an option.

Comment: The connection has to be dedicated to RSPAN I believe, but I'm not aware of a requirement for it to be a .1Q trunk, if you're willing to dedicate that Ethernet connection to this requirement. Otherwise there's an ERSPAN which uses GRE as you suggested, but it's only supported on high-end hardware (ASRs, Nexus 7ks, Cat6509...)